# g's look like q's font oddity

Tags: bug, font

It seems that when there are one line comments, g's look like q's.

here is an example:
[image]

Comment: 'g's look like q's' Realized too..

Comment: But not in IE10 at Windows 8.

Comment: noticed in chromium on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Also in Chrome in Windows.

Comment: Still happening, the `y` descender is also truncated so y looks a little more like v than it should.

Comment: @EliahKagan the dupe goes the other way