# Descenders in comments chopped off in Windows Chrome

Tags: bug, design, formatting, style

In my browser (Chrome 29 on Windows 7), [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) are chopped off in comments, which makes it fairly annoying to read, as g's look like q's (most other letters with descenders are fairly unambiguous, ypj)

Post prose is fine, it just seems to be a comment issue just on Ask Ubuntu (Stack Overflow is fine).

It looks fine under Chrome in Ubuntu (29 on 12.04), and IE10 on Win7 (same machine as where Chrome chops them)

[image: Broken descenders on AU]

Comment: I was almost sure it was my fonts... results I'm not the only one http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: I'm not sure this is something we can solve, it seems to be specific to your config.

Comment: @RolandiXor do you mean to say that it is not reproducible or it's just an edge case?  People who use Chrome under Windows isn't exactly a minor, 'edge' case.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6975/gs-look-like-qs-font-oddity seems related.

Comment: @NickT well most people here use Ubuntu ;)
I am not in Chromium right now but I've not noticed this issue before.

Comment: I've been seeing this for a while even on Firefox running on Ubuntu but only because I don't use the default font, whatever that is. If I use the default font, there's no truncation of the descenders.

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome+Windows.

Comment: `.comment-copy { line-height: **px !important }` or whatever `px` works for me.