# Bug: UbuntuRegular Font (used on this site) messed up at 12 & 13px

Tags: bug, design, font

This site, AskUbuntu.com, uses the "UbuntuRegular" font. Sometimes the font size is 14px, which displays fine, but in the "comments" (& perhaps other places), the font size is 13px, **which cuts off the bottom of low-hanging chars**.

Here is a screenshot of the string "testing 123 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" as a comment, in various sizes...

> [image: The string "testing 123 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" as a comment, in various sizes.]

Notice the "g", "j" & "y" have the bottom cut off in sizes 12 & 13px.

Here is a screenshot of the letter "g" (from the word "testing" in the screenshot above) in 13px & 14px, pasted in Paint, zoomed to 800%, grid turned on & then another screenshot taken of that...

> [image: The letter "g" in 13px & 14px, pasted in Paint, zoomed to 800%, grid turned on & then another screenshot taken of that.]

The "13px" g is really in an 8px by 11px "box" (with 1px whitespace around it — not based on actual "character box" size, since I don't know where it is from a screenshot).

At 1st I thought it was a line-height issue, but then, after ruling that out, I noticed it's a font problem. The "UbuntuRegular" font simply don't render well at 12px & 13px.

This bug really needs to be fixed by someone editing the "UbuntuRegular" font...however, AskUbuntu.com could workaround the issue by making comments either 14px or 11px...or using a different font.

Note: please see the [revision history](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/8760/revisions) for what I went thru to report this!

Comment: Looks like there's already a bug report for this : [g's look like q's font oddity](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6975/gs-look-like-qs-font-oddity?rq=1).

Comment: when this site first launched the Ubuntu font was still in beta. I'm also using it as a embedded web font. A question for the community is: should I ditch web font method and simply call font-family: ubuntu, arial, san-serif instead? This is what ubuntu.com does.

Comment: Considering that this bug report is more detailed and up to date, should we close [that one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6975/gs-look-like-qs-font-oddity) (which @André found) as a duplicate of this? Or are they to be considered different bugs? (Or something else...)

Comment: @Jin do the newer versions of the font has the same problem?

Comment: @EliahKagan I agree we should close the old one and leave this report as it's more detailed.

Comment: About the dupe: I'm sorry about that, but that dupe **doesn't** mention "UbuntuRegular" in _any_ way...so it did not come up in my searches. Also, if this is a _known issue_ (from almost a year ago)...why hasn't it been dealt with? I agree with duping the old one to this one (sorry @soandos but your old report has nothing "searchable" in it {hence, I didn't find it!}...so the dupe has to be in _this_ direction {yours to mine, instead of mine to yours})...but I just wanted to mention: I _did_ search before I posted this & did _not_ find that old report.

Comment: @Jin No, don't do that. Actually, it appears that Ubuntu.com is using the font "Ubuntu" (not "UbuntuRegular"), via the Google Fonts API. You are specifying `font-family: 'UbuntuRegular',Ubuntu,'Bitstream Vera Sans','DejaVu Sans',Tahoma,sans-serif;`...you are forcing the "UbuntuRegular" font (with no space, if that matters) to override the preference of "Ubuntu". Your version is hosted on sstatic.net, can you provide a link to where you originally got your version?...is there an official download for it? **Remember, the simplest fix is changing all 13px fonts on the site to 14px**

Comment: @Jin It's all very confusing...I don't know if the font "UbuntuRegular" (no space) is _actually_ different from the "Ubuntu" font, in the "Regular" form/weight or not. In my testing, they did seem different. **I'd say: just find the newest version of "Ubuntu" or "UbuntuRegular" & if that don't have this issue, use it!**

Comment: As of right now this is still not fixed and it's pretty annoying.